# dependabot conflict with package.lock rebase or recreate doesn't work

Tags: dependabot

@dependabot created a PR for updating one library and the PR has a conflict, I need to rebase or recreate it.

Trying to comment in @dependabot rebase or @dependabot recreate, doesn't resolve the conflict as would get updated package.lock and auto resolve.

the command was suppose to fix the conflict.

is there another way to update or recreate the dependabot PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to just rebased your PR and forced update dependabot branch.